# Ratio diverges for a converging sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence (x)  such that

$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

this ratio diverges.

Now for divergent series $10^{n^2}$,  the ratio diverges.

My question is,  is there any convergent series for which the ratio diverges.

I already find out that the limit of the converging sequence must be zero,  for satisfying the above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\frac 1 2  +\frac 1 3 +\frac 1 {2^{2}} +\frac 1 {3^{2}}+\frac 1 {2^{3}} +\frac 1 {3^{3}}+...$. the series converges but $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} \to \infty$ along a subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (assuming you meant absolute value, otherwise the claim is not true), if $L=\lim |\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|$ exists and there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have $x_n>0$, then we can test convergence using $L$. $L>1$ implies divergence, $L<1$ implies convergence and the test is inconclusive for $L=1$. Look if you can proof this and if not I can edit later and include a full proof.

To prove the claim, assume first $L<1$ and then choose an $a$ such that $L<a<1$ and obtain an $N$ so that $|x_{n+1}|<a|x_n|$ for $n\geq N$. Then show $|x_n|<a^{n-N}|x_N|$ for $n>N$. The case when $L>1$ follows by considering the sequence $y_n=\frac{1}{|x_n|}$. It should not be too difficult using these hints.